# I am stuck with R program

Tags: r

```
 C=function(a0,a1){
      x<-c(0,1);N1=F1=F2=array(0,dim=c(2,7));K=array(0,dim=c(2,7));N2=array(0,dim=c(2,7))
 for(i in 1:2){  
 for(j in 1:7){
N1[i,j]=n1[i,j]+n12[i,j]; K[i,j]=n1[i,j]+n2[i,j]+n12[i,j]+n0[i,j]; N2[i,j]=n2[i,j]+n12[i,j];

F1[i,j]=N1[i,j]/K[i,j]

F2[i,j]=N2[i,j]/K[i,j]

      alpha=exp(a0+a1*x[i])+1

     c<-exp(-((-log(F1))^(alpha)+((-log(F2))^(alpha))^(1/alpha)))
}}
return(c)
}
```

I am getting error when this loop is runing

```
Error: object 'K' not found
Error: object 'N2' not found
```

Comment: Note that R is case sensitive `n1` not the same as  `N1`. Are a0 and a1 scalars?

Comment: also take care when creating variable named `c` as `c` is an R function

Comment: the input and call to the function are missing.  Please read information at top of  [tag:r] tag page regarding how to ask a question.

Comment: I have posted the full code with all the information. Kindly have a look.